# Типы пользовательских функций

Tags: mysql

> Перечислите, пожалуйста, какие есть типы пользовательских функций?

Comment: Речь об UDF? Скалярные и агрегатные?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Теоретически ещё оконные.